# laravel custom exception handling

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel framework. I need to add a custom exception error handler. I tried to add below code to my `global.php` file:

```
App::error(function(CustomException $exception, $code)
{
echo 'Debug: CustomException<br/>';
});
```

To throw this error I used below code in one of my controllers:

```
throw new CustomException();
```

But I am getting error as CustomException not found.

I googled it for solution, but everywhere I find the same solution.

Please help me to get this fixed.

Comment: After adding below code:                                                                  App::error(function(InvalidRouteException $exception)
{
         \Log::info('InvalidRouteException');
        $code =404;
         $data = array('codeError' => $code, 'messageError' => 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.');
                                return \View::make('404')->nest('content', 'error', $data);
                
}); 
I get error route home not found exception, i am not able to see the view. I need to create a custom page where i can see the custom exception.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your custom exception first. So at the top of your `global.php` file, add this:

```
class CustomException extends Exception {}
```

Of course, you can add custom properties and methods to this class as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your class (Ex.: app/Exceptions/MyCustomException.php), then add to composer.json autoload files.

```
"autoload": {
  "files":["app/Exceptions/MyCustomException.php]
}
```

Then: run a `composer dumpautoload`

Now, you can use your `MyCustomException` class.

--

```
<?php 

class MyCustomException extends \Exception {}
```

Comment: I like this approach better, if you want to throw a lot of exceptions in your application it's better to put them in a separate file